# My html data comes after the nav menu renders?

Tags: menus

I have made a simple PHP class like this:

```
class menu {



public $html;

    function __construct() {

        this->html = '<header class="nav">'.
                        wp_nav_menu( $args = array(
                            'menu'              => 'abc',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav-list',
                            'walker'            => new thewalker(),
                            'theme_location'    => 'top_1',
                    )  ).
                    ' </header> '

    }
}
```

The class dynamically renders the menu.

in my `header.php`

I call the class like this:

```
$mMenu = new menu;
echo $mMenu->html
```

This is working the HTML is coming and the menu renders

So what's the problem?

As I have told above the HTML is coming and the menu renders but not as it should be.

The problem is the menu render first and after that, the HTML comes

Here is a dummy example like this:

First the menu renders.

- home
- about
- contact

After that the html renders

```
<header class="nav"></header>
```

What it is happening am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: add a `echo` parameter at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: @mmm it trigger an error

Answer (score -1):

Add container index in args and mention it header tag.